# afterSave member Parse Cloud Code not saving

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code, after-save

I am attempting to save a username and userId after a user registers into a Runner Class within Parse. For some reason the information is not saving and I am not receiving an error. Can anyone give some advice?

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request){
if(!request.object.existed()){
    var RunnerClass = Parse.Object.extend("Runner");
    var runner = new RunnerClass();
    runner.set("username", request.object.get("username"));
    runner.set("userId", request.object.id);

    runner.save();

    }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your afterSave is incorrectly defined. There is no response for afterSave. Only on beforeSave.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
...

}
```

Comment: I made the changes but it still did not save

Comment: Have you tried putting a log statement in your code so you can see that it is actually running?

Answer (score 0):

You have to avoid using `request.object.existed()` in your `afterSave` trigger because it currently always returns `false`. This is unfortunately due to a known bug in Parse Cloud which is yet to be fixed. Instead you have to use the workaround given here in the bug report discussion: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1675561372679121/

The workaround is to replace `request.object.existed()` with the following boolean in your `afterSave`:

```
var objectExisted = (request.object.get("createdAt").getTime() != request.object.get("updatedAt").getTime());
```

Also make sure to use `request.user` instead of `request.object` in your code

Comment: oh I don't have a Facebook and that link requests me to log in